# Map Expression Language(EL) Reference object has not been found

Tags: jsf, dictionary, el

I have following case:

`Flex` class

```
public class Flex {

private String key;
private String val;


public Flex () {
}

public void setKey(String key) {
    this.key = key;
}

public String getKey() {
    return key;
}

public void setVal(String val) {
    this.val = val;
}

public String getVal() {
    return val;
}
```

`FlexManager` class

```
public class FlexManager {


private Map<String, Flex> keyValue = new HashMap<String, Flex>();

public FlexManager () {
   populateFlexFieldMap();
}


private void populateFlexFieldMap() {
    if (keyValue.isEmpty()) {
        List<Flex> fieldds = loadKVFromFile();
        for (Flexfield : fieldds) {
            keyValue.put(field.getKey(), field);
        }
    }
}

public void setKeyValue(Map<String, FlexField> keyValue) {
    this.keyValue = keyValue;
}

public Map<String, Flex> getKeyValue() {
    return keyValue;
}
}
```

The input with managedBean is ready.

How can I get the val value in `Flex` class through `getKeyValue()` method with EL?

My approach is this: `${managedBeanName.keyValue['key'].val}`
but I get this warning in my IDE

> Reference `${managedBeanName.keyValue['key'].val}` not found

Comment: Yes. But if remove .val i don't get the warning any more. This means that the managedBean is correct and **${managedBeanName.keyValue['key']}** also. but from not  **${managedBeanName.keyValue['key'].val}**

Comment: This is not a general Java API/compiler/syntax related problem, so please don't pollute `[java]` tag with questions not about Java language. This is also not a general Java EE question, but a JSF/EL specific question, so please don't pollute `[java-ee]` tag with questions specifically about JSF/EL. Users browse by tags and expects to see questions really related to the tag in question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to type `get` in order to invoke a getter.

```
${managedBeanName.keyValue['key'].val}
```

Comment: Ok. Thank. the get was just a mistake from me(copy&paste). The problem with this approach is that i get **Reference object has not been found**

Comment: Is this a warning from the IDE or this is an error when you run the application ?

Comment: It is from IDE. Do you mean that i can ignore it?